# Jquery counting and conditional statement then resetting value

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

I finally figured out a way to add to a hidden field based on user input into dynamic text boxes.

The problem is with my script - as you can see it will grab all textboxes on the page.

I do want every text box except for the first one.  Therefore, I need to have logic that if a certain condition is met, then join the value of the textbox.  If not, do not join it.

I was thinking of something like :

```
var thenumber = 0

if (thenumber == 0) {
    do nothing;
} else {
    join the value;
    make the number increase by + 1
}
```

The code I have is as follows:

```
$(function() {
  $("#shineon").click(function(event) {
    var data = [];
    var form = $("form :input[type=text]");
    $.each(form, function(e, textBox) {
      data.push($.trim(textBox.value));
    });
    $("#mybond").val(data.join(" "));
  });
});
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this - can anyone help?

Comment: I do want every text box except for the first .....  var form = $("form :input[type=text]:not(:first)")

Comment: Your code is running when the page is first loaded, before the user has a chance to enter any input. So how can this do anything based on user input?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're having. Just put an `if()` around the `data.push()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a selector that skips the first match:

```
$("form :input[type=text]:not(:first)").each(...)
```

or you can simply test `e`, which contains the index:

```
$.each(form, function(e, textBox) {
  if (e > 0) {
    data.push($.trim(textBox.value));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  This did it.